# Paramiko recv_ready() returns false values

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to execute a number of commands remotely using paramiko, however the `recv_ready()` does not return the correct value.
For example after a `pwd \n` command it will continuously report that the channel is not still ready (obviously false). For some commands it works properly e.g. `ls`.
Is there something wrong with what I am doing, or is there an issue with paramiko?

```
import paramiko
import re
import time

def sudo_ssh(hostname, usernameIn, passIn, cmd):

    # Create an SSH client
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Make sure that we add the remote server's SSH key automatically
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    # Connect to the client
    client.connect(hostname, username=usernameIn, password=passIn)

    # Create a raw shell
    channel = client.invoke_shell()


    # Send the sudo command
    for command in cmd:
        print("CMD= " + command + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        # wait until channel is ready
        while not channel.recv_ready() :
            print("NOT READY " + str(channel.recv_ready()) + "\n \n")
            time.sleep(1)

        # Send the command
        channel.send(command)
        channel.send("\n")

        # Wait a bit, if necessary
        time.sleep(1)

        # Flush the receive buffer
        receive_buffer = channel.recv(4096)

        # If promted send the sudo pass
        if re.search(b".*\[sudo\].*", receive_buffer): 
            time.sleep(1)
            print(" TYPING SUDO PASSWORD .... \n")
            channel.send( "sudoPass" + "\n" )
            receive_buffer = channel.recv(4096)

        # Print the receive buffer, if necessary
        print(receive_buffer)

    print("Executed all of the commands. Now will exit \n")
    client.close()


com = []
com.append("sudo ls")
com.append("cd /home/user/Downloads")
com.append("sleep 5")
com.append("ls")
com.append("pwd")
com.append("cd /opt/")
sudo_ssh("myhost.com", "user", "pass", com)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `recv_ready` method is to check if the data of channel is ready to read or not i.e. data is buffered or not. It doesn't check if channel itself is ready, see - [recv_ready()](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_ready).

So you should move the `recv_ready()` while loop just before the `receive_buffer = channel.recv(4096)` to make it work.